# phpQuery - how to get plain HTML

Tags: php, phpquery

I'm using this plugin, https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery for editing the HTML content.

This is my code,

```
//$formdata contains plain HTML
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($formData);
//Some Editing
$editedData = phpQuery::getDocument($doc->getDocumentID());
//This returns object
```

This returns an object. Is there any way to get plain HTML?

Comment: https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery/blob/be908b64788a4ae6addd8f7bb61b7059c0369267/phpQuery/phpQuery/phpQueryObject.php#L1886 , so try to cast it to a string.

Comment: @Federkun Don't know how to use it. Will you please guide me?

Comment: `(string) $editedData`

Comment: @Federkun You saved my day. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the `phpQueryObject` object to a string:

```
$markup = (string) $editedData;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also (version 0.9.5)

```
$html = pq($editedData)->html();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php
i think this is what you are looking for